# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) - NodeJs Express & MongoDB Web Application

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, mongodb, express

I'm building a NodeJS Express & MongoDB Web application.

However, since I'm trying to use some AJAX feature to load and display comments on the post page, I'm getting an issue and the "post-detail" page is not displaying.

My code seems fine though. So, I'm not able to find where is the mistake.

When I check this error message:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500
> (Internal Server Error)

Is there someone who can check my code and let me know what's wrong with it?

I think there is a problem in the route or the paths?

app.js:

```
const path = require('path');
 
const express = require('express');
 
const db = require('./data/database');
 
const adminRoutes = require('./routes/admin/blog');
 
const defaultRoutes = require('./routes/home/default');
const postsRoutes = require('./routes/home/posts');
const quotationsRoutes = require('./routes/home/quotations');
const contactsRoutes = require('./routes/home/contacts');
 
const app = express();
 
app.set('views', [
  path.join(__dirname, 'views/home'),
  path.join(__dirname, 'views/admin')
]);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
 
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use('/public/admin/images', express.static('public/admin/images'));
 
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
 
app.use('/', adminRoutes);
 
app.use('/', defaultRoutes);
app.use('/', postsRoutes);
app.use('/', quotationsRoutes);
app.use('/', contactsRoutes);
 
app.use(function (req, res) {
  res.status(404).render('404');
});
 
app.use(function (error, req, res, next) {
  res.status(500).render('500');
});
 
db.connectToDatabase().then(function () {
  app.listen(3000);
});
```

routes\home\posts.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const mongodb = require('mongodb');
 
// const uuid = require('uuid');
 
const db = require('../../data/database');
 
const ObjectId = mongodb.ObjectId;
 
const router = express.Router();
 
router.get('/blog', async function (req, res) {
  const posts = await db
    .getDb()
    .collection('posts')
    .find({})
    .project({ title: 1, summary: 1, 'author.name': 1, imagePath: 1 })
    .toArray();
  res.render('posts', { posts: posts });
});
 
router.get('/blog/:id', async function (req, res, next) {
  let postId = req.params.id;
 
  try {
    postId = new ObjectId(postId);
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(404).render('404');
    // return next(error);
  }
 
  const post = await db
    .getDb()
    .collection('posts')
    .findOne({ _id: postId }, { summary: 0 });
 
  if (!post) {
    return res.status(404).render('404');
  }
 
  post.humanReadableDate = post.date.toLocaleDateString('en-US', {
    weekday: 'long',
    year: 'numeric',
    month: 'long',
    day: 'numeric'
  });
  post.date = post.date.toISOString();
 
  res.render('post-detail', { post: post });
});
 
router.get('/blog/:id/comments', async function (req, res) {
  const postId = new ObjectId(req.params.id);
  const comments = await db
    .getDb()
    .collection('comments')
    .find({ postId: postId })
    .toArray();
 
  res.json(comments);
});
 
router.post('/blog/:id/comments', async function (req, res) {
  const postId = new ObjectId(req.params.id);
  const newComment = {
    postId: postId,
    title: req.body.title,
    text: req.body.text
  };
  await db.getDb().collection('comments').insertOne(newComment);
  res.redirect('/blog/' + req.params.id);
});
 
module.exports = router;
```

views\home\post-detail.ejs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <%- include('../admin/includes/head', { title: 'Post title' }) %>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/admin/styles/posts.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/admin/styles/forms.css" />
    <script src="/home/scripts/comments.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%- include('../admin/includes/header') %>
    <main id="post-detail">
      <article class="post-item">
        <img src="/<%= post.imagePath %>" alt="<%= post.title %>" />
        <h1><%= post.title %></h1>
        <section id="post-meta">
          <address>
            <a href="mailto:<%= post.author.email %>"
              ><%= post.author.name %></a
            >
          </address>
          |
          <time datetime="<%= post.date %>"><%= post.humanReadableDate %></time>
        </section>
        <hr />
        <section>
          <p id="body"><%= post.body %></p>
        </section>
      </article>
      <section id="comments">
        <% if (!comments) { %>
        <p>
          This post might have comments. You can load them if you want to view
          them.
        </p>
        <button
          id="load-comments-btn"
          class="btn btn-alt"
          data-postid="<%= post._id %>"
        >
          Load Comments
        </button>
        <% } else if (comments.length === 0) { %>
        <p>No comments found.</p>
        <% } else { %>
        <ol>
          <% for (const comment of comments) { %>
          <li><%- include('includes/comment-item', { comment: comment }) %></li>
          <% } %>
        </ol>
        <% } %>
      </section>
      <section id="comments-form">
        <h2>Leave a comment</h2>
        <form action="/posts/<%= post._id %>/comments" method="POST">
          <div class="form-control">
            <label for="title">Comment title</label>
            <input type="text" id="title" name="title" required />
          </div>
          <div class="form-control">
            <label for="text">Your comment</label>
            <textarea name="text" id="text" rows="3" required></textarea>
          </div>
          <button class="btn">Save Comment</button>
        </form>
      </section>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

views\home\includes\comments\comment-item.ejs:

```
<article class="comment-item">
  <h2><%= comment.title %></h2>
  <p><%= comment.text %></p>
</article>
```

public\home\scripts\comments.js:

```
const loadCommentsBtnElement = document.getElementById('load-comments-btn');
 
async function fetchCommentsForPost() {
  const postId = loadCommentsBtnElement.dataset.postid;
  const response = await fetch(`/blog/${postId}/comments`);
  const responseData = await response.json();
  console.log(responseData);
}

 
loadCommentsBtnElement.addEventListener('click', fetchCommentsForPost);
```

I have noticed that when I remove the code logic for displaying comments on "post-detail.ejs", the page displays and the form for adding comments as well.

Edit: I added `console.error(error)` before `res.status(500).render('500')` and I get the following error message:

> ReferenceError:
> C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\node-com4muz-filedata-database\views\home\post-detail.ejs:30
> 28|       
> 29|
>
> > > 30|         <% if (!comments) { %>
> > > 31|
> > >
> > > 32|           This post might have comments. You can load them if you want to view
> > > 33|           them.
>
> comments is not defined
> at eval ("C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\node-com4muz-filedata-database\views\home\post-detail.ejs":40:8)
> at post-detail (C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\node-com4muz-filedata-database\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:703:17)
> at tryHandleCache (C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\node-com4muz-filedata-database\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:274:36)
> at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\node-com4muz-filedata-database\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:491:10)
> at View.render (C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\node-com4muz-filedata-database\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
> at tryRender (C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\node-com4muz-filedata-database\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:657:10)
> at Function.render (C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\node-com4muz-filedata-database\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:609:3)
> at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\node-com4muz-filedata-database\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1039:7)
> at C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\node-com4muz-filedata-database\routes\home\posts.js:49:7
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {   path:
> 'C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\node-com4muz-filedata-database\views\home\post-detail.ejs'
> }

Comment: You should log the error. Add `console.error(error)` before `res.status(500).render('500');`

Comment: I added `console.error(error)` before `res.status(500).render('500')` and I get the following error message mentioned above at the bottom of the post where I wrote "Edit".

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue.

On `views\home\post-detail.ejs` on line 49, I replaced:

```
res.render('post-detail', { post: post });
```

by:

```
res.render('post-detail', { post: post, comments: null });
```